# passing values from html to jquery after editing

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `modal` form, and after editing it, I want to pass the values from the `fields` to `jquery`. However, I'm not sure why this is not working because the `alert` is showing blank. Instead of the values within the field.

**html**

```
    <!-- Modal for edit_lesson_plans-->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Lesson Plan</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close modal-close" data-dismiss="modal"><i
                            class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form class="lesson-update-section" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-row align-center was-validated">
                            <!-- New Lesson Plans -->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">{{ edited_lp.level }}</div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">{{ edited_lp.lesson }}</div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">{{ edited_lp.description }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" id="update_lesson_plan" class="btn btn-success"
                                name="update_lesson_plan">Submit
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" id="delete_lesson_plan" class="btn btn-danger"
                                name="delete_lesson_plan">Delete
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**edited_lp is dynamically generated**

This is a copy of the `html` that gets generated.

```
<input type="number" name="level" class="form-control" id="id_level" placeholder="Lesson level number" required="">
<input type="text" name="lesson" class="form-control" id="id_lesson" placeholder="Lesson name" required="">
<textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="3" class="form-control" id="id_description" placeholder="Lesson description"></textarea>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#edit-lesson-plan-modal', function () {

    modal.find('.modal-footer #update_lesson_plan').off().on().click(function () {
        // I have tried the below as a test:
        alert($("#id_level").val());
    });
});
```

How should I be referencing the `fields` after editing it such that I can pass the values onto jquery successfully??

Could it be that it does not recognize that there is an `id_level` at all..?

Comment: Can you please click `<>` and post a [mcve] ?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more descriptive than "is not working". For starters-how do you know that it is not working?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are trying to call a function on() without the right count of parameter. you delete this line without changing your logic

Comment: @Ruzihm I've edited my question. It is not working because the `alert` jquery is showing blank instead of the values.

Comment: @mplungjan I've also shorten my code and edited some portions. I do hope it helps!.. @BlackNetworkBit, i've tried what you suggested, but it still doesn't solve the problem. the `alert` is still unable to display the values within the `fields`.

Comment: What happens if you do `alert($("#id_level").length)` ?

Comment: It returns a value of `1`. What does that mean?

Comment: It means that it's finding the input element, but that its value is an empty string, or maybe some whitespace. You should be able to verify this by seeing it hide when you do `$("#id_level").hide();`  Your problem might be caused by there being multiple elements with the id of "id_level" so it might hide something that you aren't expecting to hide.  These are all guesses, because you haven't shared a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/93889/)**.

The main problem comes from the click event, we shouldn't call `on()/off()` without passing no parameter, it should be like :

```
modal.find('.modal-footer #update_lesson_plan').off('click').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  alert($("#id_level").val());
});
```

Comment: This doesn't replicate their problem because in your example the alert doesn't show up as blank if you undo the on/off change.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because of the dynamically generating items which loads after document.ready,
So the better way is to give reference of the closest parent that existed at the time of page load.

For example.

```
Div1
  div2
      div.dynamic
```

Now if you try to get value or text directly from div.dynamic, you will get null 
so yo must reference like `$('.div2').find('div.dynamic').html()`